# Ubuntu wsl2 git getting "The remote end hung up unexpectedly" on large repos

Tags: windows, git, ssl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnutls

Getting this action for days in Ubuntu 19.04 in wsl2 on Windows.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo.git
Cloning into 'hugo'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-12): A TLS fatal alert has been received.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

- I tried recompiling git to use openssl, didn't do anything.
- I tried both ssh and https.
- I tried to modify git settings for http.
- I modified all kinds of git memory settings.
- Nothing currently on Stack Overflow is correct for this issue.
- I completely reinstalled Windows.  Nope, still hosed.

Four days of Whiskey Tango Foxtrot... then I found it.

Comment: So many threads and solutions that seem to be trying to fix the issue through git configuration but none of them will work without the right drivers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The latest Windows Hyper-V has issues with your wifi driver.  You need to get the latest from https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28876/Windows-10-Wi-Fi-Drivers-for-Intel-Wireless-Adapters?v=t

Once the new drivers are installed, you can marvel at how git in wsl2 totally does what it is supposed to.  I will never get those 5 days of my life back.  I hope this will keep you from losing 5 days of yours.

Here is the issue: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4253

Comment: This also fixed the problems I was having installing conda packages, specifically the error "CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED".

Comment: This cost me 3 days, thanks for saving the other two! :-)

Comment: Finally found this after a day of digging. Thanks for saving me the other 4.

Answer (score 2):

Update Nov. 2020: the latest comments on [WSL2 4253](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4253#issuecomment-673633785) point out to:

> set MTU to 1350 (same as VPN interface):
>
> ```
> sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1350
> # or
> ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1350
> ```

Check your MTU:

```
PS C:\> netsh interface ipv4 show subinterface

   MTU  MediaSenseState   Bytes In  Bytes Out  Interface
------  ---------------  ---------  ---------  -------------
4294967295                1          0     117945  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
  1500                1  879583365  308029141  Wi-Fi
...
  1500                1    3616963    2778319  vEthernet (WSL)

vs.

➜ ip addr | grep mtu
5: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
```

A [Windows 10 build 20231](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/10/07/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-20231/) might be needed to ensure [issue 5821 "WSL vEthernet adapter shows up as disconnected"](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5821) is fixed.

---

[B. Agustín Amenábar Larraín  explains](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4253#issuecomment-849336363):

> Until this issue I never had heard of MTU, and it was hard for me to believe that was the cause, well it is.
>
> - I'm having isues when my Pulse Secure VPN is connected and I'm trying to connect to the internal self-hosted Gitlab.
> - SSH traffic to the regular internet is fine.
> - I'm using WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04, if I drop it to WSL1, all works as expected (Same for Debian).
>
> Try upgrading your drivers first, that thidn't work for me.
>
> First open a PowerShell prompt and type:
>
> ```
> netsh interface ipv4 show subinterface
> ```
>
> You will get an output like the following:
>
> ```
>   MTU  MediaSenseState   Bytes In  Bytes Out  Interface
> ------  ---------------  ---------  ---------  -------------
> 4294967295                1          0    5974969  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
>  1500                1  2678641808  213293706  Wi-Fi
>  1500                5          0          0  Local Area Connection* 1
>  1500                5          0          0  Local Area Connection* 2
>  1500                1          0     529702  vEthernet (Default Switch)
>  1300                1       2106     509236  vEthernet (WSL)
>  1200                1  553027168   20290571  Local Area Connection* 13
>  1500                1          0   22759124  VirtualBox Host-Only Network #3
>  1500                5          0          0  Bluetooth Network Connection 4
> ```
>
> The key is in the Local Area Connection 13 MTU* (The name and value can change from machine to machine), that is the VPN interface. In my case it's 1200 which is why
>
> ```
> set MTU to 1350 (same as VPN interface):
> sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1350
> ```
>
> didn't work for me... and I didn't know how to get the VPN Interface MTU.
>
> (I also hated to install `ifconfig` which is deprecated in favor of `ip`).
>
> Now that we know, you can change the VPN MTU from Windows it in a PowerShell with Elevated Privileges,
>
> ```
> netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Local Area Connection* 13" mtu=1400 store=persistent
> ```
>
> If you want to skip the next step, you can set it to 1500, but you are leaving no room for the VPN to wrap the packets, for example I have had trouble with Github because of setting it to 1500.
>
> Then, inside your WSL2 distro, you can check your current MTU values with:
>
> ```
> ❯ ip addr | grep mtu
> 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
> 2: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
> 3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
> 4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
> 5: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
> ```
>
> We care about eth0 (the virtual ethernet connection to Windows), you have to set a matching MTU to where you left it in the previous step.
>
> ```
> sudo ip link set eth0 mtu 1400
> ```
>
> Sadly both settings get resetted every time you start a new VPN session, or restart the WSL2, or even switch from WLAN to LAN.

[Leonardo Oliveira adds](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4253#issuecomment-1009924436):

> Your solution to the problem was similar to mine, however I changed the Ethernet MTU inside on my WSL2 to the same numbering I saw in windows power shell (Ethernet WSL), and that way it worked for me.