# error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-12): A TLS fatal alert has been received. Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

At the moment I am working in WSL2 on Ubuntu (20.04.2). I have finished up my project and I want to commit my code to the repository I have made. However, whenever I want to commit I get the following error:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-12): A TLS fatal alert has been received.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I do not know what is causing this error. I know my credentials are right. These are the command I excecute to commit my code:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Finished Project"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/Myusername/my-repo.git
git push -u origin main
```

After the last command I get asked for my credentials and then I recieve the error.

I first thought it is because I am not using `openSSL` and that is causing the error. If that is the case, how do I solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
The error I receive when I use SSH:

```
Received disconnect from 140.82.121.3 port 22:11: Bye Bye
Disconnected from 140.82.121.3 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Are you using an antivirus or firewall other than Windows Defender or Windows Firewall?  If so, which one?  Are you using a proxy or TLS MITM device?

Comment: I happen to use `MalwareBytes` on my Windows 10. I do not know if I am using a proxy @bk2204

Comment: Try completely uninstalling it and restarting.  Antivirus programs other than Windows Defender often break Git or WSL2 because they improperly and insecurely tamper with connections.

Comment: Hi, I did just that but I still recieve the same error @bk2204

Comment: Instead of `https:`, can you try `ssh:` ?

Comment: Is it a MTU issue? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64837761/6309) Or a buffer one? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66235724/6309)

Comment: I tried that. Still does not work. Look up my edited question for the error when I try SSH. @Philippe

Comment: What software (name and version) and OS (name and version) are you using on the server side?

Comment: Bit random, but this could be also the origin.. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4253

Comment: @Niklas: thanks a lot, after many fails, your link finally helped me to sort it out